# CoreData relationship to same entity

Tags: swift, core-data

I am very new to Swift and CoreData and I am having trouble setting up a relationship for my entity.

I have an entity called Course and I need to be able to list possible prerequisite courses for each course.  When I add a to-many relationship it unfortunately is adding the prerequisite course to both the courses.

So for example if I have a course called Second Course and I add First Course as it prerequisite. I end up with Second Course having the prerequisite of First Course, but also First Course having a prerequisite of First Course.

And ideas on how best to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your post to include details of your model and your code for setting the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You need two entities, one called `Course` and one called `Prerequisite`.

You can give `Course` a primary key `courseIdentifier`. UUID is the usual type for identifiers.

You can give `Prerequisite` two foreign keys, `courseIdentifier` and `prerequisiteCourseIdentifier`, each again UUID.

Each foreign key identifier refers back to a course identifier from `Course`.